# getStaticProps in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I build my application using nextjs. I want to dispatch an action in my app using:

```js
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(async ({ store }) => {
  const res = store.dispatch(getDataRequest());
  return {
    props: {
      test: res
    }
  }
})
```

My actions look like this:

```js
export const getDataRequest = () => {
    return {
        type: DATA.GET_DATA_PREPARE,
    }
};

export const getDataSuccess = payload => ({
    type: DATA.GET_DATA_SUCCESS,
    payload,
});

export const getDataError = payload => {
    return {
        type: DATA.GET_DATA_ERROR,
        payload,
    };
};
```

Now i want to get the data:

```js
const Index = (props) => {

  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log("tests", props)
  }, [])....
```

But i get this in console log:

```js
{test: {…}}
   test:
    type: "GET_USERS_PREPARE"
  __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

How to get my data in console.log(), not the name of the action?

Comment: I think you need to `await` the `store.dispatch(getDataRequestCall())`. https://medium.com/@levente.balogh/how-to-use-redux-thunk-with-next-js-5daf3fcd14fd

Comment: @tobzilla90, could you help please with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410826/get-accesstoken-in-auth0